# Las rutas internas de react dan 404 aunque se rendericen

Tags: reactjs, facebook, error404, spa

Cree una aplicacion react con npx create-react-app
Cuando estaba configurando la url de privacidad para Facebook la probé en https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug y da 404 como también con cualquier subruta que no sea la base por ejemplo test.com da 200 pero o test.com/algo da 404
Usando las herramientas de desarrollo en netwock veo que el primer recurso que es la ruta da 404 y muestra el noscript del index.html
he encontrando estas preguntas similares
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905116/facebook-crawler-returns-404-for-internal-pages-of-react-app (no esta resuelta pero es lo que me paso)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955439/google-crawler-in-search-console-cant-found-routes-in-react-using-github-page(estoy en ello)

solo en producción sucede
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema parase ser por ser por ser una spa tendría que cambiarla a ssr pero como se esta organizado el proyecto queda complicado y no nos queda tiempo.
"funciono" al poner un archivo estático como test.htm en el public

Comment: ¿Qué servidor estás usando para hacer el deploy?

Comment: Se están usando los de Amazon.  si inicio el proyecto cpn npm start o con  serve -s build la primera petición da 200 pero con .... enable java Script....

Comment: No me refiero a que servicio estás usando para administrar tus servidores. Me refiero a que servidor estás utilizando. Es Apache, NGINX?

Comment: Esta de forma estática usando s3 con cloudfront